# CGI::Session and HTTP:CryptoCookie for Login (Perl)

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi, session-cookies, crypt

From what I have read so far everywhere...

CGI::Session (http://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session) seems to be the prefered way of session management using Perl. It has extensive tutorial available.

HTTP::CryptoCookie is relatively less used and known.

I was able to set cookies using CGI::Session by this simple code:

```
#Session 
my $cgi = CGI->new;
$CGI::DISABLE_UPLOADS = 1;          # Disable uploads
$CGI::POST_MAX        = 512 * 1024; # limit posts to 512K max

my $session = CGI::Session->new('driver:mysql', undef,
    {
        TableName=>'database',
        IdColName=>'id',
        DataColName=>'sessionvalue',
        Handle=>$dbh,
    });

$session->expire('+1y');

print $session->header();    


$session->flush();
```

I don't see in the source code of CGI::Session, strong signs of cryptography, so I'm a bit concerned.

I was reading the cpan tutorial, and notice this line:

"By default CGI::Session uses standard CGI to parse queries and cookies."

It got me thinking, that I can use HTTP::Cryptocookie perhaps? Instead of the standard CGI, which would make my login script more secure by sending encrypted cookies, instead of standard cookies? But the documentation about HTTP::Cryptocookie is very scarce. Nor did I find anything on google.

Perhaps someone can help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way CGI::Session works there is no advantage to using HTTP::CryptoCookie. The advantage of CryptoCookie is that it is impossable to find out what the cookie contains withiout the secreat server key. However a CGI::Session cookie only contains a session id so encrypting the session id would not help as the encrypted session id would behave exactly the same as the session id from the attackers perspective.

Comment: but CGI::Session uses MD5 by default to create sessionID, its not difficult to plant a cookie, with same session ID. So at least that is not safe right?

Comment: But it is increadably easy to just steal the cookie if your not restricting the cookie to HTTPS and if you are then the information CGI uses should be sent over HTTPS so the md5 hash is just a random number. HTTP::Cryptocookie will not pretect you aginst cookie theft which is far more of an issue than breaking the md5.

Comment: hmm, umm... I still don't get via using both is not better? I mean okay, CGI:Session is only storing a Session ID, using cookies. that cookie is also stealable right? But a cookie generated using HTTP::Crypto Cookie, which sends the same Session ID, generated by CGI::Session, should be relatively a better option, given if its tampred with, it would return garbage?

Comment: But an attacker can just send the stolen cookie and take over the session even if you encrypt it.

Comment: so whats the solution then? If one can't use either of these two?

Comment: Just use CGI::Session (and possibly HTTPS) as HTTP::CryptoCookie offers no additional security in this situation.